# Do an exclusion in build.gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I want to add an exclusion to my build.gradle because my jar doesnt run after I compile it. The problem can be fixed if some modules are excluded.
How do I do that correctly? The following code should fix the problem:

```
compile ("com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.badlogicgames.gdx', module: 'gdx-backend-lwjgl'
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most recent gradle versions (7+), you need to use the new syntax `implementation` or `compileOnly`. This should also be in a dependencies block as shown below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.badlogicgames.gdx', module: 'gdx-backend-lwjgl'
    }
}
```

[See for more info](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html)

However for gradle 6 and below, your `compile` block should work fine inside a `dependencies` block.